# Why does my HTML5 page crash when loaded from web when it doesn't locally

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Completely new to HTML5 I started playing around with canvas. This is my first ever canvas page.

It works perfectly when you run it locally (i.e. file:///), but when I upload the files to either of my webhost, the page is stuck while loading. The loading icon is spinning and the title appears, but page body is never retrieved, so obviously it gets stuck in the head somewhere.

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>1st Attempt - 2D Canvas</title>
        <meta charset='utf-8'> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.addEventListener('load', function () {
                canvas = document.getElementById('gamecanvas');
                context = canvas.getContext('2d');

                if(context){
                    // Load images and stuff
                    sprites = loadResources();

                    // Create player object
                    player = {"pos": {"x": 0, "y": 0}, "blockunder": sprites.grass};

                    // Draw a grid with a texture and stroke using my own awesome function
                    drawGrid(sprites.grass, false);
                    drawPlayer(0, 0);

                    // Define controls
                    window.onkeydown = function(event){
                        switch(event.which){
                            case 37: // ArrowLeft
                                movePlayer("left");
                                break;
                            case 38: // ArrowUp
                                movePlayer("up");
                                break;
                            case 39: // ArrowRight
                                movePlayer("right");
                                break;
                            case 40: // ArrowDown
                                movePlayer("down");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, false);

            function loadResources(){
                // Sprites
                var grass = new Image();
                grass.src = 'gfx/grass.png';

                var player = new Image();
                player.src = 'gfx/player.png';

                console.log("Loaded all resources");
                return {"player": player, "grass": grass};
            }

            function drawGrid(bgImage, drawStroke){
                cellWidth = bgImage.width;
                cellHeight = bgImage.height;
                console.log("Texture dimensions are " + cellWidth + "x" + cellHeight + " pixels");
                canvasWidth = context.canvas.getAttribute("width");
                canvasHeight = context.canvas.getAttribute("height");
                var curX = 0;
                var curY = 0;

                context.strokeStyle = '#444';
                context.lineWidth = 1;

                while(curX < canvasWidth){
                    while(curY < canvasHeight){
                        context.drawImage(bgImage, curX, curY);
                        if(drawStroke){
                            context.strokeRect(curX, curY, curX + cellWidth, curY + cellHeight);
                        }
                        curY += cellHeight;
                    }
                    curY = 0;
                    curX += cellWidth;
                }
            }

            function movePlayer(direction){
                switch(direction){
                    case "left":
                        drawPlayer(-cellWidth, 0);
                        break;
                    case "up":
                        drawPlayer(0, -cellWidth);
                        break;
                    case "right":
                        drawPlayer(cellWidth, 0);
                        break;
                    case "down":
                        drawPlayer(0, cellWidth);
                        break;
                }
            }

            function drawPlayer(addX, addY){
                addX = typeof addX !== 'undefined' ? addX : 0;
                addY = typeof addY !== 'undefined' ? addY : 0;

                context.drawImage(player.blockunder, player.pos.x, player.pos.y);
                if(player.pos.x + addX >= 0 && player.pos.x + addX < canvasWidth){
                    player.pos.x += addX;
                }
                if(player.pos.y + addY >= 0 && player.pos.y + addY < canvasHeight){
                    player.pos.y += addY;
                }
                context.drawImage(sprites.player, player.pos.x, player.pos.y);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="text-align: center;">
        <h1>Run Steve!</h1>
        <canvas id="gamecanvas" height="608" width="800">Canvas is not supported.</canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've just profiled your page's JS via Chrome developer tools and `drawGrid()` takes 98% of all processing time. I think you're running into an endless loop there.

Comment: @ComFreek If so, the drawPlayer function wouldn't be run, so I don't see how it could be looping. Does the load event by chance loop?

Comment: Oh, drawPlayer isn't run... Right.

Comment: Anyway, the actual problem - as Les Ferguson mentioned - comes from your image loading. You should probably restructure your code in order to easily pass a callback function to `loadResources()` which gets called if all resources are loaded.

Comment: @ComFreek I came to think of a solution. If I use a spritesheet instead I will only have one image to load, and therefore only one onload to handle. then I will also be able to keep my current flow, I don't like having callbacks to functions elsewhere in the code, heh. Spritesheets also seem like the easiest way to load all the parts into an object.

Comment: It's definitely annoying to handle multiple callback functions. If you ever come to Windows 8 JS development, you'll love the WinJS.Promise object. It lets you easily chain and wait for multiple callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the image paths relative to the current page?  Have you tried something like

```
grass.src = '~/gfx/grass.png';
```

e.g. if cellWidth is zero then

```
curX += cellWidth;
```

won't get you out of that loop.

Comment: I tried that earlier to no avail. Yes, they're relative to the current path.

Comment: Maybe drawGrid shouldn't be called until after the image load event has completed?

Comment: Yes yes yes yes, that's it! It says the cells are 0x0 px, so I just have to add drawgrid to the onload callback of loadresources or something similar at least... Thank you!